# Using PowerShell regex to confirm that a date is at the TAIL END of a filename

Tags: regex, powershell, date

I have a set of folders that are updated daily with a new SSRS report. SSRS reports do not have the facility to append an underscore and file creation date to the end of the filename.

A PowerShell command has been created that will append the file modified date to the start of the file, but needs to be at the end of the file. The issue is not with this part of the process - I can sort this out.

Issue: I cannot get the regex command - used to identify the files that need the change - to identify when the date is at the END of the file, not the beginning. I have tried amending the regex syntax, but have left it in now for clarity.

When run on a folder that already contains files, it appends over and over again.

Rules:
The filename is not a uniform length
The date will always have an _ character then be in YYYYMMDD format
Format: FileName_YYYYMMDD.xlsx
I cannot move renamed files out of the folder - they have to all be created and then remain in the same location

```
$ParsedDate = [datetime]::MinValue;
$Path = "C:\UserDocuments\Config Updates";
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Path |
    Where-Object {
      (-not [regex]::IsMatch($_.Name, "^\d{8}_", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)) -or (-not [datetime]::TryParseExact($_.Name.Substring(0, 8), "yyyyMMdd", [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref] $ParsedDate)) 
     } |
        ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path ($_.FullName) -NewName "$($_.BaseName)_$($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))$($_.Extension)";}
```

I am not a PS expert, and this may be a noob question.

I have tried combinations of:

`"^\d{8}_" "^_\d{8}" "^\d{8}"`

Comment: you can use `$_.Name -match '_\d{8}\.xlsx'`

Comment: ... or check what `$` means in a regular expression.

Comment: `$_.BaseName -match '_\d{8}$'`

Comment: So, to clarify, you want files that have the date at the **beginning** of the filename renamed so the LastWriteTime is appended at the **end** of the BaseName and the date that was at the leftmost part should be removed? If a date is at the start, does it separate from the next part of the filename with an underscore as well?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, I believe you want to search for files that have a date + underscore at the **beginning** of the file and these should be renamed so that the date is removed from the start and appended at the end.

Since you already tried, perhaps now some files have been appended an underscore+dae multiple times at the end.

Below code should clean these up too

```
$Path = "C:\UserDocuments\Config Updates"

# if all your files are .xlsx, then append -Filter '*.xlsx' to the below line
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File |
Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\d{8}_' } |  # search files that have a date at the beginning
ForEach-Object {
    # remove the starting date + underscore AND 
    # any repeated underscore + date from the end of the file name
    # (the ones you tried and where the date was appended over and over again)
    $name = $_.BaseName -replace '^\d{8}_|(_\d{8})*$'
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}_{1:yyyyMMdd}{2}' -f $name, $_.LastWriteTime , $_.Extension)
}
```

Regex details:

```
                    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   ^                Assert position at the beginning of the string
   \d               Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
      {8}           Exactly 8 times
   _                Match the character “_” literally
|                  
                    Or match this alternative (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   (                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      _             Match the character “_” literally
      \d            Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
         {8}        Exactly 8 times
   )               
                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
         *          You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations.
                    Or, if you don’t want to capture anything, replace the capturing group with a non-capturing group to make your regex more efficient.
   $                Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed)
```